# Swift Mapping Data to [String: Any]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, moya, json-serialization

I would like to convert a Data type to [String: Any], but the JSONSerialization tells me:

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Data'

```
var json: [String: Any]
            do{
                let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
                let encodedJson = try jsonEncoder.encode(message)
                json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: encodedJson!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
            } catch {
                log.error(error.localizedDescription)
            }
return .requestParameters(parameters: json, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

If I remove the '!' from encodedJson, then the Message occure:

> Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

If I remove the '?' from any?, then I use json without initializing it, of course

Didn't know how to fix this (new swift coder)

Hope this is not a stupid question

Comment: please share some more code, especially what is the value of message variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for this as you already have the data in `encodedJson`

```
json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: encodedJson!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
```

as `withJSONObject` expects an object not Data , also casting it to `[String:Any]` will fail

Comment: okay thanks :) , but how can I convert my encodedJson to [String: Any]?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong API, `data(withJSONObject` creates `Data` from a array or dictionary

You need the other way round. To resolve the issues remove the exclamation mark after `encodedJson`

```
json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encodedJson) as? [String : Any]
```

and declare `json` as optional

```
var json: [String: Any]?
```

---

Or – if the JSON is guaranteed to be always a dictionary – force unwrap the object

```
json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encodedJson) as! [String : Any]
```